# Python compiler giving IndexError when trying to find the similarity matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to make a movie recommendation system which requires me to find the user-user `similarity matrix` for the `top 100 users`.

On running the code I get:

```
similarMatrix[row] = top100_similar

IndexError: index 663 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 617
```

Code:

```
def getUser_UserSimilarity(sparseMatrix, top = 100):
    startTimestamp20 = datetime.now()  
    
    row_index, col_index = sparseMatrix.nonzero()  #this will give indices of rows in "row_index" and indices of columns in 
    #"col_index" where there is a non-zero value exist.
    rows = np.unique(row_index)
    similarMatrix = np.zeros(61700).reshape(617,100)    # 617*100 = 61700. As we are building similarity matrix only 
    #for top 100 most similar users.
    timeTaken = []
    howManyDone = 0
    for row in rows[:top]:
        howManyDone += 1
        startTimestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()  #it will give seconds elapsed
        sim = cosine_similarity(sparseMatrix.getrow(row), sparseMatrix).ravel()
        top100_similar_indices = sim.argsort()[-top:]
        top100_similar = sim[top100_similar_indices]
        similarMatrix[row] = top100_similar
        timeforOne = datetime.now().timestamp() - startTimestamp
        timeTaken.append(timeforOne)
        if howManyDone % 20 == 0:
            print("Time elapsed for {} users = {}sec".format(howManyDone, (datetime.now() - startTimestamp20)))
    print("Average Time taken to compute similarity matrix for 1 user = "+str(sum(timeTaken)/len(timeTaken))+"seconds")
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
    plt.plot(timeTaken, label = 'Time Taken For Each User')
    plt.plot(np.cumsum(timeTaken), label='Cumulative Time')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize = 15)
    plt.xlabel('Users', fontsize = 20)
    plt.ylabel('Time(Seconds)', fontsize = 20)
    plt.tick_params(labelsize = 15)
    plt.show()
    
    return similarMatrix


simMatrix = getUser_UserSimilarity(TrainUISparseData, 100)
```

Please tell me where exactly I need to make the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the following line

```
similarMatrix = np.zeros(61700).reshape(617,100)
```

Your **similarMatrix** is of smaller dimension than your **sparseMatrix**. Thats why you are getting index error.

You need to make the dimensions of similarMatrix equal to the dimensions of sparseMatrix. So modify the code as below

```
similarMatrix = np.zeros(sparseMatrix.shape[0]*100).reshape(sparseMatrix.shape[0],100)
```

Or for more simple structure

```
n_cols = 100
n_rows = sparseMatrix.shape[0]

similarMatrix = np.zeros(n_rows*n_cols).reshape(n_rows, n_cols)
```